# Building docker image with Django 2.0 fails

Tags: python, django, docker, build, gitlab-ci

I am currently building a docker image with the latest version of Django but during the build I get this:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9LueOB/Django/
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c INSTALL_PKGS="python-pip oracle-instantclient-tnsnames.ora afs_tools_standalone nss_wrapper openssh-clients cx_Oracle libmemcached-devel python-ldap mod_wsgi httpd MySQL-python wassh-ssm-cern wassh" &&     INSTALL_PKGS_BUILD="gcc python-devel zlib-devel" &&     yum install -y centos-release-scl &&     yum update -y &&     yum install -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs --enablerepo=centosplus $INSTALL_PKGS &&     yum install -y $INSTALL_PKGS_BUILD &&     rpm -e --nodeps centos-logos &&     pip install --upgrade &&     pip install -r requirements.txt &&     rm requirements.txt &&     yum remove -y $INSTALL_PKGS_BUILD &&     yum clean all -y &&     rm -rf /var/cache/yum &&     mkdir /var/django/ && mkdir -p /var/django/home/ &&     mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/ &&     mkdir -p /run/httpd/ && chown -R root:root /run/httpd && chmod a+rw /run/httpd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

On my requirements.txt I am using this:

```
Django==2.0
djangorestframework==3.2.1
pyapi-gitlab==7.8.4
pylibmc==1.5.0
django-logtail
python-gitlab
```

Any idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because Django 2.0 doesn't support Python 2.x anymore, try to replace "python" by "python3" in your command.

EDIT: or run "pip3" instead of "pip" when you install Django>=2.0

- as mentioned by Piinthesky here you'll find [the relevant Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/)

Comment: sorry, this is my first stackoverflow contribution ever :) , thx

Comment: No worries, but you might want to [take the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) about How To Ask a Good Question/Write a Good Answer. It is for instance preferred to edit your answer instead of hiding additional information in the comments.